# Определение количества запросов

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 20",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
do {
    printf ("%s", $myrow["field"]);
}
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Есть хостинг, на хостинге есть ограничение, на количество запросов. Методом "тыка" узнавать не охота. Сколько запросов к таблице фактически делает этот код? 20?

p.s. через while можно и так

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0, 20",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    printf ("%s", $myrow["field"]);
}
```

Но, думаю, от этого количество запросов не уменьшится.

Comment: Запрос будет 1, кол-во просмотренных строк -20. обычно ограничение именно на кол-во просмотренных строк. "Select some_fiel,(select some_field_2 from table2 where table1.id=table2.id) from table1" -запросов 2, кол-во просмотренных строк=колво строк таблицы 1*кол-во строк таблицы2(на самом деле меньше но грубо говоря так).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как бы глупо и по-снобски это не звучало(ненавижу, когда мне так отвечают)... меняйте хостинг. Я в свое время смирился с ограничением количества баз данных(идиотизм тот еще), но я не вижу смысла смиряться с ограничением числа запросов, особенно, таким жестким.

**Обоснование:** запрос тут один (Как верно заметил Даниил Вендолин), но проблема в том, что именно считать запросом. Если обращение к таблице БД - да, один. Если к движку mysql - то двадцать один. Если провайдер вредный, он может считать и подзапросы тоже, тогда вообще начнется что-то невероятное.

В итоге, придется именно тыкать, или звонить в техподдержку, или искать в пользовательском соглашении.

Comment: Вряд-ли тут запросов к движку больше двух. Функция mysql_query() для хранения результатов использует [mysql_store_result()][1], что означает, что данные будут обработаны и переданы клиенту целиком. 

Запрос к движку на каждый fetch возможен только при использовании [mysql_unbuffered_query()][2]

  [1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-store-result.html
  [2]: http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php

Comment: еще раз. =) Если нет коннекта с mysql(например, если файл с подключением битый или отсутствует), никакие функции, начинающиеся с mysql_ не работают, за исключением mysql_connect. В связи с этим возникает подозрение, что движок дергается так или иначе КАЖДЫЙ раз, но не каждый раз это является запросом именно к БД

Comment: Разумеется они не будут работать, ведь соответствующий запрос не был выполнен корректно.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string тоже требует запроса? =) Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/me/www/sandbox.dev/mres.php on line 2 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/me/www/sandbox.dev/mres.php on line 2

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() требует наличия соединения с базой, т.к. для того, что бы корректно экранировать строку, ей требуется данные об используемой кодировке БД.

Comment: Дык я про то и говорю. Им всем хоть чего-то, но нужно от движка БД. Они все теребят консольку в плане "mysql". И хотя нагрузки на сервак от этого почти никакой, въедливый админ может это отнести к запросам.

Comment: То, что многим методам для работы так или иначе требуется наличие соединение с БД, вовсе не означает, что mysql_fetch_array() делает запрос *на каждый вызов*. 

Что бы не быть голословным, кусок [метода mysql_fetch_row()][1]. Как видно, все что он делает - это перемещает указатель на следующую строку и возвращает текущую. 

  [1]: http://pastebin.com/NYpmxcsC

Answer (score 2):

Запрос делается 1

> $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM
> table LIMIT 0, 20",$db);

А это уже обработка запросов самим php

> while ($myrow =
> mysql_fetch_array($result)) { printf
> ("%s", $myrow["field"]); }

Comment: А почему же тогда при неподключенном mysql система ругается на функцию mysql_fetch_array? Что-то тут нечисто.

Comment: В плане ругается на mysql_fetch_array? ей же надо передавать какие то данные для обработки.

Но ситуация если честно поставила меня в тупик. Не сталкивался с подобными ограничениями на серверах...

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_array` отрабатывает толькоп ри активном подключении это раз, два - его задача обработка **уже полученых данных**. После выборки нам приходит resource, а mysql_fetch_array создан для того чтобы преобразовать его уже в программный хеш(в нашем случае в массив). Естественно к самому mysql'ю запрос происходит, но выборки из базы естественно нет...
Вообщем работает это примерно следующим образом - вы делаете запрос, mysql запоминает результат, потом вы вызываете mysql_fetch... - mysql преобразовывает этот результат и отдает скрипту, насколько я понимаю и знаю работает это именно так.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я знаю, к таблице будет один запрос. mysql_fetch_array() работает уже с полученным результатом.